# Android HTML5 UI not fully redrawing

Tags: android, html

We have an HTML5-base app that's running in PhoneGap, using (mostly) jQuery for the components.  Fairly regularly, the UI will be changed in javascirpt, but not completely render correctly.  You kind of need to nudge it with another touch event, which causes it to "remember" to redraw everything.  I suspect its some attempt to optimize the draw, but it forgets to update other parts of the screen that were changed.

I'm going to start modifying different css settings in the hope that it turns out to be some kind of simple bug, but I'm surprised that this isn't reported more widely (which makes me think this is due to a "magic combo" of css attributes).

So far the vast majority of testing has been on ICS.  I don't have a 2.x device handy right now, but will try that tomorrow.  My phone updated to Jelly Bean, so I'll try that and see if anything is different.

Will try to post a screenshot later.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

This works fine in Jelly Bean.  I did a search in the public Android bug DB but nothing turned up.  I'll have to dig out another phone with ICS on it and try different CSS settings and see if it goes away.